# How to take a screenshot and then upload the image to imgur through terminal?

Tags: command-line

I don't like the GUI way of taking screenshot,uploading it to imgur and get the uploaded link.

So what can I do to take a screenshot of my Ubuntu desktop, upload the screenshot to imgur.com and then get back the uploaded link from terminal?

All I have to do from terminal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Take the screenshot of your desktop

`gnome-screenshot` was the default command-line tool on Ubuntu to take a screenshot.

```
gnome-screenshot -d 10
```

Delayed the screenshot action by 10 seconds,So that you can place the desired window on front within 10 seconds.The taken images are actually stored in `~/Pictures` folder.

### Upload the image to imgur.com

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the below lines to the opened `.bashrc` file and then save it.

```
imgur() {
    for i in "$@"; do
        curl -# -F "image"=@"$i" -F "key"="4907fcd89e761c6b07eeb8292d5a9b2a" imgur.com/api/upload.xml|\
        grep -Eo '<[a-z_]+>http[^<]+'|sed 's/^<.\|_./\U&/g;s/_/ /;s/<\(.*\)>/\x1B[0;34m\1:\x1B[0m /'
    done
}
```

Source the `.bashrc` file,so that the changes can take effect,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

The above script requires `curl` package to work.So install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Then run the below command to upload the image stored in the `~/Pictures` folder to imgur.com,

```
imgur ~/Pictures/filename.png
```

### Get the link of uploaded image

[image]

**[Source](http://www.digitfreak.com/forum/tutorial/535-upload-to-imgur-from-terminal-linux)**

Comment: @user11153 are you sure?

Comment: I tested both versions locally: old version from your post didn't work (grep was reporing syntax error) and version posted on forum - that you linked as "Source" - worked flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xubuntu the xfce4-screenshooter-plugin app for the xfce toolbar allows you to link a screenshot to zimagez , as illustrated at http://docs.xfce.org/apps/screenshooter/usage - but you must register for an account there to use it (free and spamfree).

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you are looking for. It is more or less the same concept than your own response, but scripted in order to make it really silly and simple.

### Use Snap-Share

There is a script called Snap-Share that was ment to feel what you are looking for. 
What it does exactly? well...

0) Launch it:
[image]

1)it takes a picture
[image]

2)upload it, and 
[image]

3) copy the link in your clipboard. All in one move. 
[image]

### See Snap-share working:

In this video you can see **how to install** the program and **how it works** :)

**Click the image to go to the video!**
[image: Snap-share video]

### How to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install xsel scrot xclip
```

and then paste this:

```
mkdir -p ~/.snap-share-install && cd ~/.snap-share-install && wget https://github.com/rhoconlinux/snap-share/archive/master.zip && unzip master.zip && rm master.zip &&  cd snap-share-master/ &&  chmod +x  install.sh && sh install.sh && cd ~ && clear
```

[image]

Then run it with your favourite launcher. The application is called **snap-share**. :)

Hope it is useful.

**Note**. this was made mainly for personal use, it is an alpha version. I don't why but randomly from time to time (not allways) the link is mixed with some other things in the clipboard if you take more than three snaps, I don't know why or how to solve it yet. Any help appreciated.

Project Page:
https://github.com/rhoconlinux/snap-share