# How can I upload a photo to imgur from the command line and get their direct link?

Tags: command-line, upload

Is there a way I can upload some photos to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/) via the command-line and get their direct link as result in a text file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take a screenshot and then upload the image to imgur through terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/417295/how-to-take-a-screenshot-and-then-upload-the-image-to-imgur-through-terminal)

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't think it's a duplcate, this question isn't about taking screenshots, just uploading them.

Comment: @Seth linked question covers the uploading part also.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes it does, but that doesn't make it a duplicate. The answers might be similar, but the questions are still different.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The list of (mostly third-party) tools on the imgur website (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E7EQ.jpg) features three `bash` scripts:

- [*Bart's Bash Script Uploader*](https://github.com/tremby/imgur.sh) by Bart Nagel

  > A simple bash script to upload an image to imgur from the commandline. Run `imgur images/delicious/cake.jpg` to upload, print the new URL to stdout, print the delete page URL to stderr and put URL on the X clipboard for easy pasting.
- [*img Bash Script Uploader*](https://github.com/ceryn/img) by Ceryn

  > A minimalistic screenshot uploader for Linux. Supports screen selection.
- [*Imgur-Screenshot*](https://github.com/jomo/imgur-screenshot) by jomo

  > A simple screenshot bash script for Linux and OS X. Just run the script and select a portion of your screen to upload. The direct link to the image is then copied to your clipboard.

Comment: Here is a simplified version for OSX (I arrived here when I googled this): https://gist.github.com/003044274b6176f66c22

Answer (score 2):

i tried myself today on imgur and it's quite complex , the documentation is pretty bad written  so the procedure  is not clear . May i suggest to try  imagebin.ca ?!  cuz has a simpler API to upload files :

```
curl -s -F key="YOURKEY_JUST_REGISTER_ON_IMAGEBIN.CA_and go_on_profile_to get it" \
 -F file="@$1" \
 https://imagebin.ca/upload.php | awk -F':' '/url:/{gsub(/url:/,"") ; print $0 }'
```

if you are using linux and kde =>

```
qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper org.kde.klipper.klipper.setClipboardContents "$(curl -s -F key="YOURKEY_________PLEASE_EDIT_IT" \
 -F file="@$1" \
 https://imagebin.ca/upload.php | awk -F':' '/url:/{gsub(/url:/,"") ; print $0 }' )"
```